# proFTPD not working due to socket bind error

Tags: ftp, socket, proftpd

I am trying to set up an FTP server on one of my devices that runs `DietPi` and I selected `proFTPD` as a server.

I have installed the software and followed some set-up information I found [here](https://linoxide.com/install-setup-proftpd-debian-9-stretch/). But then I noticed that the service was not running. After trying to find it in via `ps aux | grep proftpd` I did not succeed.

After issuing: `systemclt status proftpd.service` I got the following:

```
● proftpd.service - LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/proftpd; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-13 22:58:49 BST; 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 26998 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/proftpd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 13 22:58:48 DietPi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon...
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi proftpd[26998]: Starting ftp server: proftpd2021-04-13 22:58:49,163 DietPi proftpd[2700
5]: mod_ctrls/0.9.5: error: unable to bind to local socket: Address already in use
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi proftpd[26998]: 2021-04-13 22:58:49,242 DietPi proftpd[27005]: error: unable to stat() 
/var/log/proftpd: No such file or directory
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi proftpd[26998]: 2021-04-13 22:58:49,244 DietPi proftpd[27005]: mod_ctrls/0.9.5: unable 
to open ControlsLog '/var/log/proftpd/controls.log': No such file or directory
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi proftpd[26998]: 2021-04-13 22:58:49,246 DietPi proftpd[27005]: fatal: ControlsLog: unab
le to open '/var/log/proftpd/controls.log': No such file or directory on line 68 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi proftpd[26998]:  failed!
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, s
tatus=1/FAILURE
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi systemd[1]: proftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 13 22:58:49 DietPi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
```

So I dug a little bit [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch4.html) and turns out that no other process runs or binds on port `21`. So, what could be the issue of the service failing here?

Furthermore, by issuing `sudo lsof -i tcp:21` I do not get any response.

Also, via `nmap` I get the following:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
53/tcp open  domain
80/tcp open  http
```

No `21/tcp` port here.

### Debug via `proftpd -nd10` on the cl:

```
roftpd -nd10
2021-04-14 08:13:45,498 DietPi proftpd[951]: using PCRE 8.39 2016-06-14
2021-04-14 08:13:45,508 DietPi proftpd[951]: using TCP receive buffer size of 131072 bytes
2021-04-14 08:13:45,510 DietPi proftpd[951]: using TCP send buffer size of 16384 bytes
2021-04-14 08:13:45,513 DietPi proftpd[951]: testing Unix domain socket using S_ISFIFO
2021-04-14 08:13:45,517 DietPi proftpd[951]: testing Unix domain socket using S_ISSOCK
2021-04-14 08:13:45,519 DietPi proftpd[951]: using S_ISSOCK macro for Unix domain socket detection
2021-04-14 08:13:45,528 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_ctrls/0.9.5: error: unable to bind to local socket: Address already in use
2021-04-14 08:13:45,532 DietPi proftpd[951]: using 'UTF-8' as local charset for UTF-8 conversion
2021-04-14 08:13:45,535 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:376
2021-04-14 08:13:45,537 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:378
2021-04-14 08:13:45,541 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:385
2021-04-14 08:13:45,544 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at parser.c:1187
2021-04-14 08:13:45,549 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_ctrls_admin.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,554 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_ctrls_admin' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_ctrls_admin.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,558 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_tls.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,562 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_tls' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_tls.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,565 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_tls/2.7: using OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
2021-04-14 08:13:45,587 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_radius.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,591 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_radius' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_radius.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,594 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_quotatab.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,599 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_quotatab' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_quotatab.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,602 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_quotatab_file.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,607 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_quotatab_file' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_quotatab_file.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,609 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_quotatab_radius.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,612 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_quotatab_radius' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_quotatab_radius.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,617 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_wrap.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,625 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_wrap' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_wrap.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,628 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_rewrite.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,633 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_rewrite' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_rewrite.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,636 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_load.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,639 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_load' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_load.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,643 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_ban.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,648 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_ban' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_ban.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,651 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_wrap2.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,656 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_wrap2' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_wrap2.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,660 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_wrap2_file.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,664 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_wrap2_file' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_wrap2_file.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,668 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_dynmasq.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,673 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_dynmasq' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_dynmasq.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,675 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_exec.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,681 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_exec' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_exec.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,683 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_shaper.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,688 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_shaper' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_shaper.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,692 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_ratio.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,696 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_ratio' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_ratio.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,699 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_site_misc.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,704 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_site_misc' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_site_misc.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,706 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_sftp.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,722 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_sftp' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_sftp.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,725 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_sftp/1.0.0: using OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
2021-04-14 08:13:45,737 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_sftp_pam.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,741 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_sftp_pam' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_sftp_pam.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,744 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_facl.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,749 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_facl' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_facl.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,752 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_unique_id.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,757 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_unique_id' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_unique_id.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,762 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_copy.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,768 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_copy' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_copy.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,773 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_deflate.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,787 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_deflate' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_deflate.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,789 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_deflate/0.5.7: using zlib 1.2.11
2021-04-14 08:13:45,792 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_ifversion.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,798 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_ifversion' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_ifversion.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,800 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_memcache.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,805 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_memcache' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_memcache.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,809 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_memcache/0.1: using libmemcached-1.0.18
2021-04-14 08:13:45,812 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_tls_memcache.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,815 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_tls_memcache' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_tls_memcache.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,815 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_readme.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,823 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_readme' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_readme.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,825 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loading 'mod_ifsession.c'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,831 DietPi proftpd[951]: mod_dso/0.5: loaded module 'mod_ifsession' (from '/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_ifsession.so', last modified on Tue Mar 10 23:03:08 2020)
2021-04-14 08:13:45,835 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at parser.c:1190
2021-04-14 08:13:45,838 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:388
2021-04-14 08:13:45,844 DietPi proftpd[951]: DenyFilter: compiling regex '\*.*/'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,857 DietPi proftpd[951]: retrieved UID 1000 for user 'dietpi'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,862 DietPi proftpd[951]: retrieved GID 1000 for group 'dietpi'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,866 DietPi proftpd[951]: <IfModule>: using 'mod_quotatab.c' section at line 53
2021-04-14 08:13:45,868 DietPi proftpd[951]: <IfModule>: using 'mod_ratio.c' section at line 57
2021-04-14 08:13:45,871 DietPi proftpd[951]: <IfModule>: using 'mod_delay.c' section at line 61
2021-04-14 08:13:45,873 DietPi proftpd[951]: <IfModule>: using 'mod_ctrls.c' section at line 65
2021-04-14 08:13:45,874 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_ctrls.c:114
2021-04-14 08:13:45,877 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_ctrls.c:117
2021-04-14 08:13:45,878 DietPi proftpd[951]: <IfModule>: using 'mod_ctrls_admin.c' section at line 73
2021-04-14 08:13:45,879 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:376
2021-04-14 08:13:45,879 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:378
2021-04-14 08:13:45,879 DietPi proftpd[951]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:385
2021-04-14 08:13:45,879 DietPi proftpd[951]: processing configuration directory '/etc/proftpd/conf.d/'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,880 DietPi proftpd[951]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:388
2021-04-14 08:13:45,907 DietPi proftpd[951]: UseReverseDNS off, returning IP address instead of DNS name
2021-04-14 08:13:45,907 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: 
2021-04-14 08:13:45,907 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Config for DietPi FTP:
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: IdentLookups
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DeferWelcome
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: MultilineRFC2228
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DefaultServer
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ShowSymlinks
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: AllowRetrieveRestart
2021-04-14 08:13:45,908 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: AllowStoreRestart
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: TimeoutNoTransfer
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: TimeoutStalled
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: TimeoutIdle
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DisplayLogin
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DisplayChdir
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ListOptions
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DenyFilter
2021-04-14 08:13:45,909 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DefaultRoot
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RootLogin
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: UserID
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: UserName
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: GroupID
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: GroupName
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Umask
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DirUmask
2021-04-14 08:13:45,910 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: AllowOverwrite
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: TransferLog
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: SystemLog
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: WtmpLog
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: QuotaEngine
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Ratios
2021-04-14 08:13:45,911 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: DelayEngine
2021-04-14 08:13:45,912 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_facl/0.6: registered 'facl' FS
2021-04-14 08:13:45,921 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_tls/2.7: generating initial TLS session ticket key
2021-04-14 08:13:45,924 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at mod_tls.c:4815
2021-04-14 08:13:45,927 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_tls.c:4818
2021-04-14 08:13:45,930 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_tls/2.7: scheduling new TLS session ticket key every 3600 secs
2021-04-14 08:13:45,935 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: binding to text domain 'proftpd' using locale path '/usr/share/locale'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,936 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: using locale files in '/usr/share/locale'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,939 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'ko_KR': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,943 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'bg_BG': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,945 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'ja_JP': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,948 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'en_US': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,951 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'fr_FR': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,954 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'es_ES': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,958 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'zh_TW': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,960 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'zh_CN': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,964 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'it_IT': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,968 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: mod_lang/1.1: skipping possible language 'ru_RU': not supported by setlocale(3); see `locale -a'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,971 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at mod_log.c:2151
2021-04-14 08:13:45,974 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_log.c:2154
2021-04-14 08:13:45,976 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at mod_rlimit.c:555
2021-04-14 08:13:45,978 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_rlimit.c:558
2021-04-14 08:13:45,980 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: set core resource limits for daemon
2021-04-14 08:13:45,981 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at mod_auth_unix.c:1338
2021-04-14 08:13:45,986 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_auth_unix.c:1341
2021-04-14 08:13:45,989 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: retrieved group ID: 1000
2021-04-14 08:13:45,991 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: setting group ID: 1000
2021-04-14 08:13:45,993 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: SETUP PRIVS at main.c:2594
2021-04-14 08:13:45,994 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at main.c:1862
2021-04-14 08:13:45,995 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: deleting existing scoreboard '/run/proftpd.scoreboard'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,996 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: opening scoreboard '/run/proftpd.scoreboard'
2021-04-14 08:13:45,998 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at main.c:1889
2021-04-14 08:13:46,002 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at mod_ctrls_admin.c:1632
2021-04-14 08:13:46,002 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: opening scoreboard '/run/proftpd.scoreboard'
2021-04-14 08:13:46,005 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_ctrls_admin.c:1634
2021-04-14 08:13:46,007 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: ROOT PRIVS at inet.c:409
2021-04-14 08:13:46,008 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: RELINQUISH PRIVS at inet.c:459
2021-04-14 08:13:46,009 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Failed binding to ::, port 21: Address already in use
2021-04-14 08:13:46,011 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Check the ServerType directive to ensure you are configured correctly
2021-04-14 08:13:46,011 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Check to see if inetd/xinetd, or another proftpd instance, is already using ::, port 21
2021-04-14 08:13:46,011 DietPi proftpd[951] 127.0.0.1: Unable to start proftpd; check logs for more details
```

### Debug via `strace proftpd | grep -E "SOCKET|sock"`

```
getpeername(0, 0xbe8a6c1c, [16])        = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 3
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [131072], [4]) = 0
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [16384], [4]) = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/test.sock"}, 110) = 0
unlink("/run/test.sock")                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/proftpd.sock"}, 110) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
write(2, "2021-04-14 11:08:40,739 DietPiHo"..., 1292021-04-14 11:08:40,739 DietPi proftpd[2682]: mod_ctrls/0.9.5: error: unable to bind to local socket: Address already in use
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 6
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 6
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 4
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=2682, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44402), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [28->16]) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40796), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [28->16]) = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
```

Comment: Some other process has the FTP port open, probably an earlier attempt. `sudo lsof -i tcp:21` will show which.

Comment: @waltinator It does not return anything. I forgot to mention on the post that I have also tried looking via ```lsof```. I updated the post with this information as well.

Comment: It says "local socket". Perhaps a UNIX socket is meant? Also, the log file is ill-configured. After fixing that, perhaps you get more info in the log. Or try launching the server on the command line, with debug options if available.

Comment: I created the directory ```/var/log/proftpd``` so now the logging issue is solved. The socket binding persists as expected. I updated the post to include debug information given by ```proftpd -nd10```

Comment: Try to start it manually with `strace`, so you'll know what socket causes the "already in use" error.

Comment: @A.B I added further information on the post with output from ```strace```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strace` output indicates that the error is caused by the attempt to create `/run/proftpd.sock`, which apparently already exists.

Try `fuser /run/proftpd.sock` to see if any process is holding onto it; it will report the PID numbers of any such processes. Then use `ps -fp <PID number here>` to get more information about the process(es) in question.

If it's `systemd`, you might need to do something like `systemctl stop proftpd.socket; systemctl disable proftpd.socket` to get rid of it. (In this case, DietPi's default ProFTPD configuration might have been tailored to use `systemd`'s *socket activation* mechanism - essentially a mechanism that can replace the classic `inetd`/`xinetd` in running the FTP daemon on-demand only. As you seem to want to run ProFTPD as a classic stand-alone service, you would need to disable `systemd`'s socket for it.)

If it's some other process, you might want to kill it and figure out how to prevent it from getting started again.

But if `fuser` lists no processes at all, it might be that the `/run/proftpd.sock` is simply a left-over from an earlier test run that did not start correctly; in that case, run `rm /run/proftpd.sock` and try `systemctl start proftpd.service` again.

Comment: Dear user. Thanks for your reply. I have tried after running the strace to see wether some process holds the proftpd.sock, namely I ran the ```fuser /run/proftpd.sock``` but I didn't get any PID back. So I do not know how to proceed...

Comment: @Broxigar Then you can just delete `/run/proftpd.sock` and try starting proftpd again, as I suggested at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yep. That solved it. :). Thank you for your time and your assistance.